# Jenkins pipeline resolve artificat

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jfrog-cli

I am unsuccessfully trying to get a jar from artificatory. Here is my pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
            stage('Stop all services') {
                agent {label 'master'}
            steps {
                    script{
                        def server = Artifactory.server 'Java_Artifactory'
                        def downloadSpec = readFile 'file'
                        def buildInfo1 = server.download spec: downloadSpec
                }}}}}
```

and this is my file:

```
{
 "files": [
  {
      "pattern": "java-team-archiva-cache/com/rsa/jsafe/cryptoj/5.0/cryptoj-5.0.jar",
      "target": "myTest/cryptoj.jar",
      "props": "p1=v1;p2=v2"
    }
 ]
}
```

this is my Console Output:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Stop all services)
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_Pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] getArtifactoryServer
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] artifactoryDownload
Downloading artifacts using pattern: java-team-archiva-cache/com/rsa/jsafe/cryptoj/5.0/cryptoj-5.0.jar
Beginning to resolve Build Info published dependencies.
Finished resolving Build Info published dependencies.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
Finished: SUCCESS
```

as you can see there is no errors in the output, but still I ant find my jar anywhere.
I also try to save it under /tmp/ but the result was the same